# im having a strange issue in netlogo with an ifelse statement

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I'm asking about an issue on net logo as I'm doing a project in it. I'm making a flocking simulation but when i tried to impalement other behaviors using ifelse statements, but when i put the ifelse statement into it, they don't follow any behaviors, rather they just move.

Here's the code:

```
breed [Birds Bird] breed [Hawks Hawk]

to Setup   clear-all   reset-ticks   create-Birds Number_of_Birds[
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor]   create-Hawks Number_of_Hawks[
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor] end

 to Start   ask Birds[
    set color white
    ifelse (Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance = 0)
    [
      set heading Migration_Direction
      let closest-Birds max-n-of Target_Group_Size (other Birds) [distance myself]
      let Group_Heading mean [heading] of closest-Birds
      let centroidx mean [xcor] of closest-Birds
      let centroidy mean [ycor] of closest-Birds
      set heading (Migration_Direction +( attraction * (Group_Heading)))
      fd 1
      set heading ( attraction * (towardsxy centroidx centroidy) )
      fd 1
    ]
    [
      let Closest_Hawks max-n-of 1 (Hawks) [distance myself]
      set heading (mean [heading] of Closest_Hawks + 180)
      fd 1
    ]   ] end
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at the definition of [`in-radius`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-radius) in the NetLogo dictionary:

> Reports an agentset that includes only those agents from the original agentset whose distance from the caller is less than or equal to number.

It says that `in-radius` *reports an agentset*.

Now let's take a look at your `ifelse` condition:

```
ifelse (Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance = 0)
```

The definition tells us that the `Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance` part reports an agentset (i.e., all the hawks that are in the radius). The `=` sign then compares that agentset to the number `0`. But an agentset is not an number! It can never be equal to zero.

I suppose that what you want is to compare *the **number** of hawks in the radius* to the number `0`.

One way to do that would be to use the [`count`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#count) primitive, which reports the number of agents in an agentset:

```
ifelse (count Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance = 0)
```

That would work, but I would not write it like that. NetLogo has the much nicer [`any?`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any) primitive, which you can use like this:

```
ifelse (not any? Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance)
```

This expresses your intent in a much clearer way.

You could also invert the order of your `ifelse` clauses to avoid the `not`:

```
ifelse (any? Hawks in-radius Reaction_Distance)
[
  ; get away from hawks...
]
[
  ; flock normally...
]
```